# How to find unique objects in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, unique

It appears that [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) does not quite support `objects` in all cases:

```py
v = np.array(["abc",None,1,2,3,"3",2])
np.unique(v, return_counts=True)
```

results in

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

I can do `np.unique(v.astype(str))` but that would lose the distinction between `3` and `"3"`.
Is that the only way?

Comment: `None` does not support comparison < >

Comment: @Epsi95: `None == "3"` works just fine. And `"3" < 3` does not work either. So?!

Comment: That is true, since None is before that is why it is caught. Try with `v = np.array(["abc",1,2,3,"3",2,None,])`

Answer (score 0):

`help` of `numpy.unique` says

```
unique(ar, return_index=False, return_inverse=False, return_counts=False, axis=None)
    Find the unique elements of an array.
    
    Returns the sorted unique elements of an array. There are three optional
    outputs in addition to the unique elements:
    
    * the indices of the input array that give the unique values
    * the indices of the unique array that reconstruct the input array
    * the number of times each unique value comes up in the input array
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    ar : array_like
        Input array. Unless `axis` is specified, this will be flattened if it
        is not already 1-D.
```

Thus it fail as one of your objects has not `__lt__` method needed for sorting, if you wish to just found unique but order is irrelevant to you might do

```
import collections
import numpy as np
v = np.array(["abc",None,1,2,3,"3",2])
cnt = collections.Counter(v.ravel())
uniq = [k for k,v in cnt.items() if v==1]
print(uniq)
```

Output:

```
['abc', None, 1, 3, '3']
```

Comment: Or just `set(v)`. No need for collections.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to define `__lt__` for all your objects in your array. Another easier method that will not require sorting and only depends on equality operator (which will work for washable objects only) is using set in python:

```
np.array(list(set(v)))
```

output:

```
array([1, 2, 3, None, '3', 'abc'], dtype=object)
```